# reactive forms validators.required is not allowing value 0

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

`inputField: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])`

when the user enters '0' in the field, the error required is applied on the control.

Zero should be considered as a value.

Answer (score 6):

By default, If you enter anything into formControl element angular form will treat it as truthy value -

```
inputField: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required])  //valid
inputField: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])  //invalid
```

But yes, you can add some regex pattern as well to check value match for `0` only, for example -

```
inputField = new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]*$/)])
```

Answer (score 4):

you're mistaken somewhere.

stackblitz shows 0 meets a required validator: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmqvtq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you enter anything into formControl element angular form will treat it as truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

You could create method, that matches whatever regex you input and then validates based on that. For example, lets not allow zero.

```
control: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.notAllowed(/^0/)])

  /**
   * Regex form validator
   */
  notAllowed(input: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const forbidden = input.test(control.value);
      return forbidden ? {notAllowed: {value: control.value}} : null;
    };
  }
```